# Ruby code for hex offset

Tags: ruby, hex, offset

I should to rewrite Ruby code made by previous coder, but i don't understand what this code do.
It should add offset to hex code, but how?

`line.gsub(/\\x([[:xdigit:]]{2})/){|i| i[-2..-1].to_i(16).chr}.unpack('C*').inject(''){ |r,b|<<('%02x ' % b)}`

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't do anything (except producing a compile-time error), because

```
 |r,b|<<('%02x ' % b)
```

is syntactically incorrect.